# RoR Translation Interpolation - with values from other translations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Say I have these translations:

```
en:
  article:
    name: "article"
```

Is it possible to do something like:

```
test1: "We have zero #article.name.pluralize"
test2: "There is an error in your #article.name"
test3: "Title for this page is: My #article.name.pluralize.capitalize"
```

I'm not too fussed about 1 and 3 (i.e. performing additional functions on the variable), but test2 would be a great help.

This also begs the question: is this a good way to structure translation files? I ask this because other languages can be structured in a completely different way. I'm just thinking of ways to DRY up my translation files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can possibly define a translation like this:

```
test1: "We have zero %{things}"
```

And then, somewhere in your code you can use it like this:

```
I18n.t(:test1, :scope => [:flashes], :things => t(:name, :scope => [:article] ))
```

or, using different notation:

```
I18n.t("flashes.test1", :things => I18n.t("article.name"))
```

Comment: Thanks. That is a better way to structure things. I added a separate question regarding this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315179/effective-way-to-structure-translations-in-ror if you care to take a look.